# Button element on my webpage is not sizing/scaling appropriately in mobile view of the site

Tags: html, css, less

I wrote some code for a button that should be aligned the same way on mobile view as it does in desktop view. The  has
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />`
in it, and the webpage will scale itself down appropriately, but the button I have on the page does not. It overlaps onto other elements, and in general looks sloppy, while on desktop, it is placed and aligned correctly.

Here is the code for my button:

```html
<span>
  <!-- There is an SVG path to an alert icon that goes here. I cut it out. -->
  <div style="display:inline">
    <button id="flyOut"> 
      <span id="my-msg">{{Message "alert-msg"}}</span>
    </button>
  </div>
</span>
```

Here is the CSS LESS for my-msg:

```css
#my-msg{
  color:#007398;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-bottom: #EB6500;
  font-family: arial;
}
```

Instead of overlapping and being misplaced, how would I go about changing the code so that it is mobile responsive?

Answer (score 0):

```
.full-width {
  /* 100% of viewport width */
  width: 100vw;
}
```

You can use it like so:

```
<html class='full-width'>
```

or like this:

```
<html style='width:100vw;'>
```